# How to get value as integer from JTextField in swing?

Tags: java, swing

Actually i'm using oracle jdbc type4 thin driver. And I'm creating registration form in swing with eclipse with following columns pid,name,addrs.
the problem is i'm getting only string value which method is `ps.setString=(2,JTextfiled.getText());`
but i'm not able get int value like `ps.setInt(1.getxxx());` 
can anyone guide me how to insert int value to database.

```
//prepare query
String query1 ="insert into employee values(?,?,?,?,?)";
//create preapare Statement
ps = con.prepareStatement(query1);
//set params
ps.setString(1,textField.getText());
ps.setString(2, textField_1.getText());
ps.setString(3, textField_2.getText());
ps.setString(4,textField_3.getText());
ps.setString(5, textField_4.getText());
//execute query
int count = ps.executeUpdate();
if(count==0)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record not Inserted");
}
else
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record inserted into database successfuly");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) to convert your string to an `int`, then use `PreparedStatement#setInt` to set it on the statement for insertion. E.g.:

```
ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
```

You'll want to catch `NumberFormatException` in case the values in the text fields are not valid integers.

Comment: Combine it with a `JFormattedTextField` or `JSpinner` to reduce the risk of the exception ;)